# jquery selector help

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, telerik

I have a telerik listview that is generating to much html for my slide show. The slide show only should contain two  items but it contains 6. I am not sure why it generating extra code, but I was hoping there is a way with jquery to only select the appropriate ones that are created. I am using [This](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/adv.html) Slide show, and Here is the markup that creates the slide show.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ctl00_MainContent_PhotoListData_lvSlideShowList_ctrl0_itemPlaceholderContainer').cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
            delay:-1000// choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you link to a sample page?

Comment: What is the innerHTML of the `#ctl00_MainContent_PhotoListData_lvSlideShowList_ctrl0_itemPlaceholderContainer` element? And why is the ID so long?

Comment: You need to be more descriptive of your problem. And, #ctl00_MainContent_PhotoListData_lvSlideShowList_ctrl0_itemPlaceholderContainer .. longest string i have seen so far used for id.

Comment: thats an easy fix, sorry about that I know thats a long id but it was temparary till i fixed the slide show issue. So please forgive me and look past the long id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to hard-code such a long id, you shoul always use this instead when you have server controls:

```
var element = $('#<%=your_sever_control_id.ClientID%>');
```